# Skip invalid xml element with XmlStreamReader

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

I want to parse my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<REPLY SERVICENAME="ServerWrapper">
    <ROWSET name="ServiceName">
        <ROW num="1">
            <AMOUNT_TOTAL>26865</AMOUNT_TOTAL>
            <REQUESTED_SEARCH_VALUE>eur</REQUESTED_SEARCH_VALUE>
            <SELECTED_ID>ABC,XYZ</SELECTED_ID>
            <AMOUNT>10</AMOUNT>
            <ABC,XYZ.AMOUNT>26865</ABC,XYZ.AMOUNT>
            <ROWSET name="ServiceName.DATA">
                <ROW num="1">
                </ROW>
                ...
             </ROWSET>
        </ROW>
    </ROWSET>
</REPLY>
```

In this XML, I need to skip an invalid element `<ABC,XYZ.AMOUNT>26865</ABC,XYZ.AMOUNT>`. I'm using `XMLStreamReader` class for parsing the xml.

My parser class:

```
public Object decode(String xml) {
    XMLInputFactory xmlFactory = null;
    String textValue = "";
    xmlFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        xmlFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, Boolean.TRUE);
        xmlFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
        xmlFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.TRUE);

        XMLStreamReader xmlReader;
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());

        xmlReader = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stream);

        while (xmlReader.hasNext()) {
            int eventType;
            try {
                eventType = xmlReader.next();
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
                continue;
            }

            switch (eventType) {
                case XMLEvent.START_ELEMENT:
                    treePath.append("/").append(xmlReader.getLocalName());
                    attribute(xmlReader);
                    break;
                case XMLEvent.END_ELEMENT:
                    endElement(xmlReader, textValue);
                    break;
                case XMLEvent.END_DOCUMENT:
                    endDocument();
                    break;
                case XMLEvent.CHARACTERS:
                    textValue = xmlReader.getText();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error on parsing data", ex);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    LOGGER.info("Decode finished on[{}]", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    Object[] response = new Object[1];        
    response[0] = responseList;
    return response;
}
```

But while parsing I'm getting an exception:

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,237]
Message: Element type "ABC" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:601)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: By definition, an `XmlStreamReader` expects to receive syntactically valid XML.  You will need to read in the lines yourself and replace the invalid element name with something valid before passing it to the XML reader.

Comment: @JimGarrison is there any way to skip the invalid element ?

Comment: You already have the entire input XML in a String. You could wrap a `FilterReader` around a `StringInputStream` and remove the offending content on the fly.