# Encoding for unicode and &amp; characters

Tags: java, string, encoding, protocol-buffers

I am trying to save the below string to my protobuff model:

```
STOXX®Europe 600 Food&BevNR ETF
```

But while printing the protomodel value it's displayed like:

```
STOXXÂ®Europe 600 Food&amp;BevNR ETF
```

I tried to encode the string to UTF-8 and also tried `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(str)`, but it failed. I'm getting this string by parsing the XML response from server. Any ideas ?

Ref: XML parser [Skip invalid xml element with XmlStreamReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954738/skip-invalid-xml-element-with-xmlstreamreader)

Comment: Where do you get this String from ?

Comment: I'm getting this string from XML by parsing it.

Comment: You should change XML parser encoding. Please provide your parsing code and XML file (at least part of it)

Comment: This is an example of data that I'm getting from server as xml form.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954738/skip-invalid-xml-element-with-xmlstreamreader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting the XML parsing should be better than needing to unescape everything. Please check below a test case showing this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isCoalescing", true);
    ReaderInputStream ris = new ReaderInputStream(new StringReader("<tag>STOXXÂ®Europe 600 Food&amp;BevNR ETF</tag>"));
    XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(ris, "UTF-8");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        reader.next();
        if (reader.hasText())
            sb.append(reader.getText());
    }

    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output:

```
STOXX®Europe 600 Food&BevNR ETF
```

Comment: Â® is just an example of special character. What if other special characters come ? I need a generic one.

Comment: You will have to fix the encoding on the XML parsing then, before unescaping the string.

Comment: I'm using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954738/skip-invalid-xml-element-with-xmlstreamreader

Comment: Try passing `UTF-8` in the encoding of the reader  `xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(InputStream stream, String encoding)`.

Comment: But unfortunately in the xml response from server has the text STOXXÂ®

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107952/discussion-between-krishnanunni-p-v-and-dambros).

Comment: this solution worked for me. But in linux environment the string is STOXXÂ® as such. What is wrong here ?

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV does `reader.getEncoding()` return the correct value?

Comment: i think the string is already UTF-8 encoded. So we need to decode it, right ?

Comment: I just edited your answer in this way: InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream("<tag>STOXXÂ®Europe 600 Food&amp;BevNR ETF</tag>".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    reader = xmlFactory.createXMLStreamReader(stream); This solved the encoding issue in linux environment. Please check,

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have  protobuf method with me to solve this issue:

```
ByteString.copyFrom(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(string), "ISO-8859-1").toStringUtf8();
```

[Documentation of ByteString](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/ByteString#copyFrom%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: And the reason this works: that string looks like it was UTF-8 encoded, but got displayed using ISO-8859-1. So parsing it as ISO-8859-1 (which is just turning code points into bytes 1-on-1) and then decoding it as UTF-8 reverses the process.

Comment: Which solution is better ? Correcting the XML parsing or this one ?

Comment: The former, obviously. Better to get it right upon reading the data, than to patch it up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

As the text comes from XML use:

```
s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(s);
```

This is way better than unescaping HTML which has hundreds of named entities `&...;`.

The two rubbish characters instead of the Copyright Symbol are due to reading an UTF-8 encoded text (multibyte for Special chars) as some single Byte Encoding, maybe Latin-1.

This wrong conversion just might be repaired with another conversion, but best would be to read using a UTF-8 Encoding.

```
// Hack, just patching. Assumes Latin-1 encoding
s = new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// Or maybe:
s = new String(s.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Better inspect the reading code, and look wheter an optional Encoding went missing: `InputStreamReader, OutputStreamWriter, new String, getBytes`.

Your entire problem would be solved by using an XML reader too.